# actionscript 3.0 file download from ftp server using air

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, ftp

I've developed an application and now I'm trying to download a file from ftp server. I'm using codes from [here](http://suzhiyam.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/as3-ftp-client-part-ii-uploaddownload/)

Codes are working on PC and I'm able to get file. However, when I build an ipa and test on I-Pod, device is unable to connect server. I traced by using a text field on screen and there is nothing on screen whenever I press download button. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Devices don't allow direct socket connections. You'll probably have to figure out how to do it with an http request of some sort.